# How to use different services (ftp, vpn) if all ports are blocked except 80 and 443

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, proxy, blocking

Unfortunately the sysadmin blocked all ports in my network except 80 and 443 so just the browser works properly. Previously I've used VPN, (S)FTP, SSH to work remotely. Now I cannot do that.

Could you advice me something to get rid of this issue?

For example is it possible to redirect all needed port to 80 or 443 via some kind of proxy or anything else?

Comment: Why don't you ask your sysadmin if your need is to work remotely?

Comment: The circumstances are a bit complicated beacuse it is a hostel belonging to an army base where I live just temporarly (but for a longest period). It's impossible to ask the sysadmin to write me uniqe firewall rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to deal with this is to setup a VPN connection to a remote server listening on port TCP443 (which you claim is open). [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) (but see also the [ever helpful Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN) on this)  can easily do that. You should rent a remote VPS (I have one for $3/mo.) and setup the server on it. Then, by choosing to route **all** of your traffic thru the VPN, you will re-acquire the ability to ssh, ftp, and so on.

The reason why this works is that connections to port TCP443 are encrypted, and your OpenVPN would be just another encrypted connection which it would be impossible to distinguish from the others.